# Artifactory query if docker images are present

Tags: docker, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

How can I use AQL query to find if a list of docker images are present in a specific repo?

For example, I need to find if 'abc-repo/username/' contains a list of imagename:tag

Thanks,
Sudha

Answer (score 4):

First, it is important to understand that in Artifactory (as a docker repo) an Artifact Path contains the image name and tag you're looking for, so for example, a single layer (= an artifact) path may look like this:

```
 docker-repo/my-docker-image/123/sha256__abcde...
```

where the image name is 'my-docker-image' and the tag is '123'.

So to answer your question, in your case you can use an AQL querying repo and path like so:

```
items.find(
{
    "repo":{"$eq":"docker-repo"},
    "$and":[
                {"path":{"$eq":"my-docker-image/123"}}
           ]
}
```

)

Or (and that would probably be what I would do), use the CLI and query using repo and path like so:

```
jfrog rt s  docker-repo/my-docker-image/123/
```